# SQL Server - strange behavior with UDF and bitwise operations in ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2014 SP3, and I stumbled upon a very strange behavior (or a documented behavior I couldn't find) with the ORDER BY clause.
Why in the following example the count variable isn't always 5?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.F_SmallintSignedToUnsigned (@Value SMALLINT)
RETURNS INT
AS  
BEGIN 
    RETURN CAST(@Value AS INT) & 0xFFFF;
END;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
    , SmallintValue SMALLINT NOT NULL
);
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (SmallintValue) VALUES
(-100), (10), (3000), (-1), (-32768);

DECLARE @count INT;

PRINT 'Count variable should always be 5?';

SET @count = 0;
SELECT @count += 1 FROM dbo.TestTable TestT ORDER BY dbo.F_SmallintSignedToUnsigned(TestT.SmallintValue);
PRINT 'Count with UDF in ORDER BY: ' + CAST(@count AS VARCHAR(10));

SET @count = 0;
SELECT @count += 1 FROM dbo.TestTable TestT WHERE TestT.SmallintValue <> 999 ORDER BY dbo.F_SmallintSignedToUnsigned(TestT.SmallintValue);
PRINT 'Count with UDF in ORDER BY + WHERE clause: ' + CAST(@count AS VARCHAR(10));

SET @count = 0;
SELECT TOP(100) @count += 1 FROM dbo.TestTable TestT ORDER BY dbo.F_SmallintSignedToUnsigned(TestT.SmallintValue);
PRINT 'Count with UDF in ORDER BY + TOP(100): ' + CAST(@count AS VARCHAR(10));

SET @count = 0;
SELECT @count += 1 FROM dbo.TestTable TestT ORDER BY CAST(TestT.smallintvalue AS INT) & 0xFFFF;
PRINT 'Count with bitwise operation in ORDER BY: ' + CAST(@count AS VARCHAR(10));

SET @count = 0;
SELECT @count += 1 FROM dbo.TestTable TestT WHERE TestT.SmallintValue <> 999 ORDER BY CAST(TestT.smallintvalue AS INT) & 0xFFFF;
PRINT 'Count with bitwise operation in ORDER BY + WHERE clause: ' + CAST(@count AS VARCHAR(10));

SET @count = 0;
SELECT TOP(100) @count += 1 FROM dbo.TestTable TestT ORDER BY CAST(TestT.smallintvalue AS INT) & 0xFFFF;
PRINT 'Count with bitwise operation in ORDER BY + TOP(100): ' + CAST(@count AS VARCHAR(10));
```

Comment: Why use `@Count +=` and not `@Count = Count(*)`? YOu're get much more reliable result if you treat your data as what it is, a data set.

Comment: @Larnu this is just an example, my actual implementation is a bit more "complicated", just wanted to point out these misleading results with the order by.

Comment: If you add `+ ' (' + Cast( @@RowCount as VarChar(6) ) + ')'` to each of your `print` statements you'll get your fives. `select @count +=1` is an assignment, not a counting operation. What you are doing is, at best, quirky and I wouldn't be surprised if the results are unpredictable.

Comment: @HABO as I stated in my previous answer to Larnu, my actual need is not to count records; this is just a simple example of what I'd like to achieve (be it a running total, a concatenated string, etc), and wanted to know if the result is actually unpredictable by design, and why.

Comment: Perhaps you would do better thinking of it as [`Sum`/`Over`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [`String_Agg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) provide documented behavior. If it isn't documented then you shouldn't <sorry> count </sorry> on it. It's much like the observation that the results always come out in the "right" order, so I don't need to use `order by`. Until they don't. "Unpredictable by design" is something you find in CPU manuals.

Comment: I've been using this trick in some situations in which the built-in functions are not of help. With the order by on "simple" columns and option maxdop 1 to avoid parallelism it seems to work, but I guess I just can't take it as a deterministic method (pity!)